# list populated from DB is making calls to DB again when queried

Tags: c#, linq

```
foreach (var item in ReturnList)
        {
            if (item.EmptyAmounts)
            {
                var list2Variable = !List2.Where(a => a.TaxFormLineId == item.TaxFormLineId).Any(a => a.EmptyAmounts == false);
                item.EmptyAmounts = list2Variable ;
            }
        }
```

In this above code, the List2 is populated already from joining few tables. While executing this, it behaves differently in 2 environments with 2 different databases.

While debugging, i found that

Env 1: the List2 has data. list2Variable is populated from List2 as expected.

Env 2: the List2 has data. **Its making DB calls inside the loop everytime List2 is queried inside the loop.**

Any ideas?

Comment: What type is List2? Is it just an Iterator, or is it really a List? And of what?

Comment: Is this because in the first environment `EmptyAmounts` evaluates to `true` after each iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

`List2` is most likely an `IQueryable` instance representing a deferred query against the database; it's not until you iterate over the query that then query is actually performed. So when you do this:

```
!List2.Where(a => a.TaxFormLineId == item.TaxFormLineId).Any(a => a.EmptyAmounts == false);
```

...it's tacking on a `where` clause to your query, and `Any` is what actually will cause the query to execute.

If you want `List2` to be pre-populated with data and for the `Where` and `Any` to test against pre-fetched data, not against the database, you'll want to convert `List2` to something like a list:

```
List2 = (some LINQ stuff).ToList();
```